# mediawiki java or bash script to create a page

Tags: mediawiki, edit

I spent almost a day looking for a script to login and create a media wiki page. The latest mediawiki has deprecated many actions like login and all samples I found were using deprecated actions.

I tried https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox as well with no luck.

Could someone give me a script that is tested with the latest mediawiki

https://www.mediawiki.org

Comment: "no luck" is not a useful error description if you want to get more useful answers than "try to be more lucky next time". Using the old login API with [bot passwords](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords) is not deprecated.

Comment: I am just looking for a command line tool which would take my userid and password as stdin and create the page using a file. Example
wikicreatescript PAGEURL wikirawdata.txt

Comment: As I said, use `action=login` and a bot password. (Or you could use [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers) which is better but more complicated to write.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best client for Mediawiki is [mwclient](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient), it is written in Python so you should be able to easily create tiny script for page creating and run it in bash.

```
site = mwclient.Site("mywiki.com", path = '/w/')
page = site.Pages['MyNewPage']
page.save("Contents on new page")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java

It gives a several frameworks to many programming languages, include java.
I recomended using **Wiki.java** framework; which is a single class that allow you to make various edits in wikipedia.
If you used the latest frameowrk; you can login to wikipedia using the following code:

```
Wiki wiki = new Wiki ("en.wikipedia.org");
wiki.login ('username','password');
```